# Is there a Telegraf plugin which takes in queries to read data from Influxdb and then post them on a kafka topic using the Kafka output plugin?

Tags: apache-kafka, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

Using Telegraf plugins, there is a way to read data from InfluxDb and publish it to a Kafka topic.

But is there a way to read the data on demand and place it on a Kafka topic? Like a query based demand.

I can do a query based read through REST API (curl GET).

There are HTTP Listener plugins but these are only for POST methods. 
None for GET method where I can query a subset of data from InfluxDb and place them on a Kafka topic. In this case, kafka would be the output plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using Kapacitor's [Kafka event handler](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/event_handlers/kafka/). Kapacitor can be configured either in batch mode or streaming mode. In case of streaming mode, if the condition met for processing, Kapacitor event handler will process the record immediately  and send to Kafaka cluster. Please refer [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/event_handlers/kafka/) for more details.